# Can someone help me correct this sentence?

Tags: past-tense

"Marvelling at the palace which seem like arised from the fantasy, one can certainly imagine wandering around with Aladdin, Princess Jasmine and the Genie in the 1,001 Arabian Nights Tales."

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

"Marvelling at the palace which seemed like it had arisen from a fantasy, one could certainly imagine wandering around with Aladdin, Princess Jasmine, and the Genie in the *1,001 Arabian Nights* tales."

Answer (score 0):

"Marvelling at the palace as if it arose from fantasy, one could certainly imagine of wandering around with Aladdin, Princess Jasmine and the Genie in the 1,001 Arabian Nights Tales."